# NGINX html comes out malformed

Tags: html, css, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using nginx in a docker container which is serving out static content. It's run in Kubernetes as a sidecar to another service in the same file.

However, the issue is that although the same exact HTML page is being served (I checked using a text comparer) the page looks malformed on the web server (but fine when I render it locally)

So because of this, it makes me think that there is an issue with serving some of the css, js, or image files

Here's part of the Kubernetes deployment

```
containers:
      - image: <OTHER IMAGE>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: <imagename>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8888
      - image: <MY NGINX IMAGE>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: <imagename>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
      restartPolicy: Always
```

[The nginx file](https://paste.mod.gg/isivicazeg.nginx)

[The Dockerfile](https://paste.mod.gg/tiloxigamu.cpp)

Here is the file path of the actual proxy (static content in kiwoon-pages)
[image: the file paths]

Here is the static content

[image: file paths of static content]

Is there anything that looks glaringly wrong here? Let me know, thanks!

Comment: I believe I didn't specify mime types, so I will make sure to do that and get back to this question with the result.

Comment: Yes! This fixed the issue. It seems the browser did not apply CSS or JS because it was sent with the mime type text/plain. I added mime types to the proxy and it worked fine now!

Comment: Can you describe how you solved the problem and what was the cause in the answer ?
It may be helpful for other community members.

Comment: Since I did not include mime types, all CSS and JS files were not being used, which resulted in my site looking malformed. Therefore, by adding ```include mime.types;``` in my server block, which includes the default nginx mimetypes that come in every nginx proxy, correct mime types were assigned to my css and js files which led them to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Since **@tymur999** has already solved this issue, I decided to provide a Community Wiki answer just for better visibility to other community members.

It's important to know that browsers use the MIME type, to choose a suitable displaying method.
Therefore, the web server must send the correct MIME type in the response's `Content-Type` header.

In the [MIME types documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types), we can find an important note:

> Important: Browsers use the MIME type, not the file extension, to determine how to process a URL, so it's important that web servers send the correct MIME type in the response's Content-Type header. If this is not correctly configured, browsers are likely to misinterpret the contents of files and sites will not work correctly, and downloaded files may be mishandled.

In nginx, we can use the `types` directive to map file name extensions to MIME types of responses (see: [NGINX documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types)):

```
Syntax: types { ... }   
Default:    
types {   
    text/html  html;   
    image/gif  gif;   
    image/jpeg jpg;   
}
```

> Context:  http, server, location

**NOTE:** A sufficiently full mapping table is distributed with nginx in the `mime.types` file.

---

As an example, suppose I have a simple website - a single HTML (`index.html`) and CSS (`mystyle.css`) file.

```
$ ls /var/www/html/
index.html  mystyle.css
$ cat /var/www/html/index.html 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css"/>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
$ cat /var/www/html/mystyle.css 
body {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

Without the correct MIME type for CSS, my website doesn't work as expected:
**NOTE:** The `text/css` MIME type is commented out.

```
$ grep -Ri -A 3 "types {" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
        types {
                text/html                             html htm shtml;
                # text/css                              css;
        }
```

[image]

When the `text/css` MIME type is properly included, everything works as expected:

```
grep -Ri -A 3 "types {" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
        types {
                text/html                             html htm shtml;
                text/css                              css;
        }
```

[image]